# Load an npm module inside a typescript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm working in a project and I need to load a module that it is not in typescript. In a folder called `typings` I have all the typescript modules while in the folder `node_modules` I have the javascript version. The problem is that when I try to import that module it is not found. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: how are you importing? show us teh codez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `typings` you don't have an implementation of the module in typescript but the type definitions of a javascript module (which might be in `node_modules`). See [definitelytyped.org/](http://definitelytyped.org/) for more information.

You can install the type definitions of a mudule with

```
$ tsd query PACKAGE_NAME -a install --save
```

With this command your `tsd.json` file will be updated and when you execute `tsd reinstall`, that package will be installed again. That's also nice if other people are working on the project. They can install all type definitions with `tsd reinstall` (as long as `tsd.json` is in your repository).

In you `.ts` file you import the javascript module with

```
import MODULE = require ('MODULE');
```

and load the type definitions with

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/MODULE/MODULE.d.ts" />
```

Of course you have to adapt the path and names.
If you don't have type definitions, you can load your javascript module with

```
declare var require: any;
var MODULE = require('MODULE');
```

Answer (score 0):

`tsd install node`

Followed by

`var theJsModule = require('the-js-module');`

Compile with `--module commonjs`